# How to separate grouped Sequelize managed transactions so they do not timeout?

Tags: node.js, optimization, transactions, sequelize.js, timeout

We run sequelize v4.44 and some CRUD actions have a promise chain of [sequelize managed transactions](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#managed-transactions) that do several queries and mutations, sometimes with joins, associations, `.scope()`. Sometimes they have some small non-sequelize promises mixed in between, non-blocking or no API calls AFAIK

However the [sequelize dialect options](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/) (like `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` ) are not used directly for watching a transaction duration limit; a promised based wrapper is used featuring `setTimeout()` to associate a timeout id with a sequelize.transaction and error out if the set duration time is exceeded, which is currently (1 min)

How do I best optimize the the managed transactions to become faster so that they stay under the 1 minute limit and avoid timeout errors?
Do I need to use the `separate` [option](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/d447bc8a9ba2f843c68eb0923e6152b1eb183588/packages/core/src/transaction.ts#L512) to split composite transactions?
Should I limit a single transaction to the wrapper function rather than a single timeout wrapper for n+1 transactions (chained by (`.then()`)?

Thanks